# Create EJB project using Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers

Tags: eclipse, ejb, java-ee-7

I am using Eclipse Kepler (Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers).
I was trying to create an EJB project but I could not found it in the available list : In the Java EE perspective, select File > New > Other.
Am I missing something ?
Do I need to download any plugin ?

Answer (score 0):

I m not familiar with Eclipse Kepler but I use Eclipse Europa to create EJB by selecting The option of Dynamic Web Project and adding the required libraries to it.

Comment: I need to add a separate EJB project.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the wrong Eclipse IDE , I just download the correct Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers and hence I can add EJB project.